# PyQGIS: drop features belonging to same group conditional on other attribute expression

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I have a polygon shapefile on which I need to eliminate features belonging to the same group (identified by a variable/attribute XG) on the base of the values taken by another variable YA. In particular, given some features with same XG, I would like to keep the one with the highest YA value.
There are many groups for which XG identifies only one feature.

Below is a sample structure of my attribute table in case I did not explain my self well.
What I have:

```
XG YA  
5 100  
5 130  
5 210  
2 0.4  
2 0.1  
1 0.6
```

What I would like to get using Python console in QGIS:

```
XG YA  
5 210  
2 0.4  
1 0.6
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in this case I would recommend to use a virtual layer. It is not pyqgis but much simpler. May be it is not the answer you expected...the definition query would be (where mylayer is the name of your layer):

```
select geometry, xg, max(ya) from mylayer group by xg
```

you can also put this into a simple pyqgis script:

```
vlayer = QgsVectorLayer( "?query=select geometry, xg, max(ya) from mylayer group by xg;", "vlayer", "virtual" )
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(vlayer)
```

Comment: thanks it worked perfectly! I don't know much about these queries, do you have some good references about their use in Python/QGIS?

Comment: Only the documentation and then you can have a look on spatialite query syntax. Qgis uses Spatialite for that. https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/create_layers.html#creating-virtual-layers